# Problems building expression tree from postfix notation

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, expression-trees, postfix-notation

I'm currently writing an impreter for simple mathematical expressions (constants and simple 
arithmetic).

The problem I'm having is with building an expression tree from a postfix formatted expression. What I've done works fine in most scenarios, [but not with this example from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm#Detailed_example).

If I evaluate the expression `3 + 4 * 2 / ( 1 - 5 ) ^ 2 ^ 3`, I get the result `3,0001220703125` even though the result should be `3,001953125`.
The reason for this seems to be that the expression tree looks like `3+((4*2)/((1-5)^(2^3)))` instead of `(3+((4*2)/(((1-5)^2)^3)))`.

The postfix notation of the original expression looks like `3 4 2 * 1 5 − 2 3 ^ ^ / +`

**Any suggestions how to get the expression tree as I want it to be?**
Below is the postfix to expression tree code and some tests which is in C# but should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
public MathExpression Parse()
{
    var tokens = this.ToPostFix(_tokens);
    var stack = new Stack<MathExpression>();
    foreach(token in tokens)
    {
        if(token.IsOperand())
        {
            // Push the operand on the stack.
            stack.Push(new ConstantExpression(token.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Assert(token.Type == TokenType.Operator, "Expected operator.");
            var op = (Operator)token.Value;
            var right = stack.Pop();
            var left = stack.Pop();
            var expression = new ArithmeticExpression(op, left, right);
            stack.Push(expression);
        }
    }
    Debug.Assert(stack.Count == 1, "More than one expression on stack.");
    return stack.Pop();
}
```

And some tests:

```
[Test]
public void Wikipedia_Example_Can_Be_Evaluated()
{
    var expected = 3+4*2/(1-5)^2^3; // 3,001953125
    var actual = MathExpression.Parse("3 + 4 * 2 / ( 1 - 5 ) ^ 2 ^ 3")
                               .Evaluate(); // 3,0001220703125
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); // Not equal :(
}

[Test]
public void Can_Convert_To_Prefix()
{
    string expected = "3 4 2 * 1 5 − 2 3 ^ ^ / +"
    string actual = MathExpression.ToPostFix("3+4*2/(1-5)^2^3")
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual); // Works as expected
}
```

Comment: Yes, I wrote the example as infix to clarify how I want the binary expression tree to look like. The code shows how I build the tree from postfix notation.

Comment: Then it seems you omitted the code that made the error. Can you add the postfix for the sample?

Comment: I've added the postfix for the expression. Same as the one in the Wikipedia example, so I think I can rule out errors there.

Comment: I deleted that comment, I was assuming left-to-right.

Comment: No. Just trying to refresh my memory a little bit. Been a long time since I read about all this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WikiPedia page contains this remark:

> `^` is evaluated right-to-left

<strike>I don't see your code taking that into account, `^` is treated the same as the other operators, as left-associative.</strike>

That means that your interpretation might be wrong:

`x ^ 2 ^ 3`  => `x^(2^3)` => `x 2 3 ^ ^`

and your code and original answer (3,0001220703125) are correct.

Comment: The question is how I take that into account.

Comment: I understand. If I declare a variable in C# like double value = 3+4*2/(1-5)^2^3 (see the first unit test) I will get 3,001953125 instead of 3,0001220703125. I remember different calculators in school interpreting expressions differently. Maybe this is the case as well?

Comment: Re the unit test: `3+4*2/(1-5)^2^3` is _not_ doing any exponentiation. `^` is the exclusive-or. In fact `expected` will be an `int`. Try to avoid `var`, and type `2.0` for const doubles.

Comment: I tried with `double expected = 3.0D+4.0D*2.0D/(1.0D-5.0D)^2.0D^3.0D` but it gives me the same result. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: `^3.0D` should not even compile. There is no Exp/Power __operator__ in C# so it will be difficult to compare against C# syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I originally wrote that code in VB.NET and ported it to C# for the question (which in retrospective might have been a bad idea), since there was a higher chance of someone answering it. But it's still interesting why VB.NET evaluates the expression like that.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx) __operators are said to be _left associative_ in Visual Basic__. I take that to mean _all_ operators, including `^`.

Comment: Ok. That really explains it. Thank you VERY much for your patience with me.